# Saving .doc file to .docx file in word 2007 losing the bullet list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

I am having an word document which has number of styles and bullets and the file format is .doc(97-2003 Document) and i opened in that document in MSWord 2007 and save as .docx file format.(With maintain compatibility with 97-2003 checkbox clicked).

After saving the document i lost all the bullets and the size of the document also decreased.

I dont know why can any one help me...

Comment: dude, if you opened it in Word 2007 and the bullet points were still there, and you lost them when saving it as docx, then save it as something else and see if they are retained.

Comment: If i save .doc or .rtf bullet list are there.. If i try to save .docx it lost bullet list only..

Comment: no harm in keeping it saved as doc or rtf. rtf will always be readable and docs too. ms word is extremely good for backwards compatibility of older formats even wordperfect 5 and works 6 and maybe more if i had not just gone by defaults when I installed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/), it's a converter to several filetypes.

Let me know if it works!

About Zamzar (taking from the meta information of the website): *Free conversion between document, image, music, video, audio, eBook, compressed and CAD formats. No download or account required.*

Comment: +1 to remove the -1. you're right he can try converting it through zamzar or through youconvertit and see if it retained the bullet points.

Comment: the -1? The previous site I linked?
Was *.docx to *.doc sorry for that!

Comment: The answer's just a bare link, with no details about where the links go to. I do know about zamzar, not all do.

Comment: Yes, and  I think he should've written the word zamzar in his post. And mentioned what it does. Not just for the sake of the original poster, but for others. Pretty bad answer considering how simple it was to give. But as a solution to this simple problem it's reasonable. But he should also have said some alternative routes covering if it doesn't work, instead of "tell me if this doesn't work".

Comment: @HellScream even your comment is badly written and unreadable, you've actually confused things. Maybe you did deserve -1.  His question is doc to docx, and zamzar does that. So despite your comment, your answer would apply to that.

Comment: I'm just trying to help him out but have limited time, jezus.

And it is possible that the conversion still was failing and then I could try and help him, that is why I said let me know if it works :)

Comment: Sry for the late rply friends.. I tried that Zamzar website convert my file but still its losing the bullets.. It's not working..